# Should android up action save state of current activity?

Tags: android, material-design

The use of the Home / back button is well documented within the android docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/up-action.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html), however it does not state if the expected usage will "save changes" to the state of the current activity.

My specific situation is a user is presented with a data entry form (list of equations) that can be manipulated (and possibly have the data messed up by applying crazy maths) so i want the user to be able to leave "without saving changes".
It is unclear if this is the expected action of the home button, or if it is expected to allow users to return to the activity as they left it.

Clarification would be grand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My expectation is that the user is prompted when pressing Up, informing the user that her information will be lost. When she confirms, loose the information, when she cancels stay on the Activity.

Edit: Better to only show the prompt when there was any editing done. Otherwise it might be just annoying to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the help!. I have implemented as you suggested a back button that if changes ave been made has a confirm dialog. While i am not sure its the "perfect" solution, as most apps want every change to be instantly saved, this certainly works for mine. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The HOME/BACK buttons are means provided to the user to navigate in an App. The BACK button normally acts as a means to navigate user to the parent of the current screen (Activity) or to the last screen in the chronological order.

HOME button is a quick way to suspend whatever the user is currently doing and come back to it later. So when the user next comes back to the app again, he can start from where he left. Android framework by default will retain the APP or UI state (mostly), so you have to hardly do anything if you want to stick to the default behaviour. But it really depends on the nature of the App. There are apps, which will trim down to the app main screen next time when the user launches (But these are very few).

Also note, that it is really upto the system how long it is going to retain the app's state in the background. Sometimes it gives to memory pressure and user has to start from scratch next time when he launches the app.

hope I answered your question

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It is certainly the back button (in app, not system) that i should use. By the sounds of it, the system decides hence the lack of "consistency"